Why does this conditional type work statically but not dynamically?
I have produced a conditional type that correctly returns a union of valid array indices:
type ArrayIndices<
  N extends any[],
  Acc extends number[] = []
> = Acc['length'] extends N['length']
  ? Acc[number]
  : ArrayIndices<N, [...Acc, Acc['length']]>;


type Indices = ArrayIndices<['a', 'b', 'c']>; 
// type Indices = 0 | 1 | 2

and have used it to alter the path creation conditional type on this page to account for arrays:
type Path<T, Key = keyof T> = Key extends keyof T
  ? T[Key] extends unknown[]
    ? `${Key & string}[${ArrayIndices<T[Key]>}]` | `${Key & string}`
    : T[Key] extends object
    ? T[Key] extends infer R
      ? `${Key & string}.${Path<R, keyof R>}` | `${Key & string}`
      : never
    : `${Key & string}`
  : never;

type Paths = Path<{ arr: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }>; 
// type Paths = "arr" | "arr[0]" | "arr[1]" | "arr[2]"

But when I try to apply it dynamically it fails (testFunction will here only accept arr as a valid path prop, and not - for example - arr[0]):
const testObject = { arr: ['a', 'b', 'c'] };

const testFunction = <T, P extends Path<T>>(obj: T, path: P) => {};

testFunction(testObject, 'arr[0]');
// Argument of type '"arr[0]"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"arr"'

Why does this happen, and what - if anything - might be done to correct it?

The type of testObject is not { arr: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }. It's { arr: string[] }.  So nothing "static" vs "dynamic" is involved here.  If you use a const assertion you can get { arr: readonly ['a', 'b', 'c'] } and then if you allow your types to deal with readonly arrays like this playground link shows, then it just works. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer (although it does seem like the question has operates under false premise and should maybe be [edit]ed). If not, what am I missing?

of course string[] duh@me thx j. no need to add an 'answer' this comment is enough for me and hopefully others too

Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted without a trace; I'll post an answer.

This doesn't have much of anything to do with "static" versus "dynamic" application of a conditional type. It's that your "static" and "dynamic" applications are acting on different types, and therefore yielding different results.
The core problem here is that testObject is of type {arr: string[]}, which contains no information about which numeric indices might actually exist on arr.  If you want that information to be preserved, you'll need to be more careful with how types are inferred.  One easy approach is to use a const assertion on your array literal:
const testObject = { arr: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const};
// const testObject: { arr: readonly ["a", "b", "c"]; }

That's now very close to what you were testing... except that the array is a readonly tuple and not a read-write tuple.  Your utility types don't properly handle readonly array types. You can fix that by just changing unknown[] and any[] to readonly unknown[] and readonly any[], since readonly arrays are supertypes of read-write arrays:
type ArrayIndices<
  N extends readonly any[], // <--
  Acc extends number[] = []
> = Acc['length'] extends N['length']
  ? Acc[number]
  : ArrayIndices<N, [...Acc, Acc['length']]>;


type Indices = ArrayIndices<['a', 'b', 'c']>; 
// type Indices = 0 | 1 | 2

type Path<T, Key = keyof T> = Key extends keyof T
  ? T[Key] extends readonly unknown[] // <--
    ? `${Key & string}[${ArrayIndices<T[Key]>}]` | `${Key & string}`
    : T[Key] extends object
    ? T[Key] extends infer R
      ? `${Key & string}.${Path<R, keyof R>}` | `${Key & string}`
      : never
    : `${Key & string}`
  : never;

And now everything just works as you expect it to:
testFunction(testObject, 'arr[0]'); // okay

Playground link to code
